# 'The message was deleted by:' is not callable

Tags: python

I am having this error and it's so annoying. I am trying to learn but I am getting so many errors.
The error is in the: description = `["][1]`The message was deleted by:"(id),

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    if on_message_delete:

        botcommands_channel = client.get_channel(777547375463759882)
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Message", description = "The message was deleted by:"(id), color=0xFF0000)
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Programmer : HussainAlko#3131")
        myEmbed.set_author(name="HussianAlko")
    
        await botcommands_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure to read the guidelines for how to post questions. As a rule of thumbs, post data, code and be clear about what you need help with. Also, show what you have done to solve the problem on your own. You need to explain what it is you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to call the string

```
"The message was deleted by:"
```

as if it were a function.

If you mean to interpolate `id` into the message, you can use e.g. f-strings:

```
f"The message was deleted by: {id}"
```

That said, though, I don't see a definition for `id`, so the result of that string will probably not be what you want...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

```
description = "The message was deleted by:"(id)
```

There you have a string which you than want to call with the parameter id. This does not work. Instead you should use string concatenation. This can be done with "+". So in your example you could have:

```
description = "The message was deleted by:" + str(id)
```

Comment: I want it to mention the one who deleted the message, but I got "The message was deleted by:<built-in function id>
"